# unable to save qgis as default project or using save as option

Tags: qgis

I trying to save qgis default template but i got an error

```
  Error save current project as default
```

I am usuing the option of qgis

```
Setting -> Option -> General-> Set current project as default
```

please help me why I am unable to set project as default

even When I tried to save as project that also I cant save

Comment: u got an error message when saving your project ? what kind of message ? can't u add a screen capture ?

Comment: Common advice would be "check your data path", but this particular case looks odd to me. It seems as though both .qgis2 folder and data folder are affected... Do you happen to have login name with any non-english character? (or space?)